# SSRS PDF Corrupted on Export

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report-viewer2010

I have a problem with export to PDF from a report server.  When exporting to PDF from the report viewer control in a ASP.Net web site written in VS2010 and C# for a certain report in the general case it works fine.  However, with certain parameters passed to this same report it outputs a corrupted PDF file.

One peculiarity is that this parameter combination that corrupts the PDF file is the one that outputs the most amount of data.  All other render formats work fine in all scenarios.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I found another combination of parameters that causes it as well.  The relationship is clearly the size of the output. Both sets of parameters produce large outputs.

Comment: Check to see how the report is setup in design view. If it is not setup properly to fit to a single page width and height, it may be pushing stuff to different pages in an odd way when alot of data is returned. Maybe your C# application is having a hard time with that?

Comment: I think it could be related to the page height.  Modifying that value fixed it for some reports, but it is broken for others.  It is very odd that height configurations can cause corrupted PDF files.  I don't think it is specific to the ASP.Net site.  The file fails to export from the ReportServer as well.

Comment: Hmm that's odd then. Normally it doesnt fail on the report server as well. It normally just pushes the data to multiple pages and looks really strange. Not sure why that would be. What are you using to open the PDF's?

Comment: I was using Adobe PDF Viewer - latest version.  Turns out the issue is fixed in Cumulative Update 6 of SSRS 2008 R2.  Installing Service Pack 2 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Adobe PDF Viewer - latest version. Turns out the issue is fixed in Cumulative Update 6 of SSRS 2008 R2. Installing Service Pack 2 fixed the problem.